# Is the Eee Pad Transformer able to determine latitude and longitude?

Tags: geolocation, asus-eee-pad-transformer

Does the Eee Pad Transformer have a way to determine it's current latitude and longitude (e.g. a GPS chip)? I am writing an application where I need those values to identify, for example, if I am upstairs or downstairs or in the car.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And how do you think you can determinate upstair/downstair location?

Transformer has GPS receiver, but its precision in indoor use is way too low to have a reliable altitude reading.

Comment: Aircraft have a barometric altimeter (and military ones have also a radar altimeter) for this purpose. I'm afraid but AFAIK you can't do what you're asking for with the GPS data. And keep in mind that on the first floor GPS reception will be really bad.

Comment: I don't know any "standard computing platform" (already built) suitable for this kind of tracking. And I thing you'll have to deploy your own network of "beacons" to do what you want from a mobile device. Something like a bluetooth/wifi xmitter in each room, with specific antenna irradiation patterns (to avoid overlapping areas). From the device, you can then read SSID and signal strenght and triangulate the position of the device.